# Infill likelihood for a continuously observed continuous-time process

Tags: likelihood, gaussian-process, state-space-models, continuous-time

Consider a continuous-time stochastic process $y(t)$ having the following linear
(Gaussian) state-space representation for $t \geq 0$

$$
  \left\{ 
   \begin{array}{c c l}
   \text{d}{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}(t) &=& \mathbf{A} \boldsymbol{\alpha}(t)\,
   \text{d}t
   + \text{d}\boldsymbol{\zeta}(t)\\
   y(t) &=&  \alpha_1(t) 
   \end{array}
   \right.
$$

where $\boldsymbol{\zeta}(t)$ is $p$-dimensional Wiener process
process and $\mathbf{A}$ is a $p \times p$ transition matrix.  Assume
that the process $\boldsymbol{\alpha}(t)$ is stationary, so the
initial state $\boldsymbol{\alpha}(0)$ and $y(0)$ are assumed to be
drawn from their respective stationary distribution. Assume as well
that the state-space representation is observable. Examples of this
framework include Continuous-time Auto-Regressive (CAR) processes
such as the famous Ornstein–Uhlenbeck.

Consider the process on a bounded time interval, say $t \in [0,\, 1]$.
A well-known context is that of *partial observations*: the process
$y(t)$ is observed at times $t_i$ with $t_1 < \dots < t_n$. The
likelihood is easily defined and it can be computed in $O(n)$
operations using Kalman Filtering. Now

1. How can we define the *infill likelihood* a.k.a. the *continous record
   likelihood*, corresponding to the (ideal) case where a complete continuous path
   $y(t)$ would be observed on a time interval $[0, \, 1]$?
2. What relation would then exist between the infill likelihood and
   the limit of the likelihood for the partial observations when the
   observation times $t_k$ fill the interval $[0, \, 1]$? The filling
   condition can be expressed as: $\max_k \{t_{k} - t_{k-1}\}$ tends to
   zero with $t_0:=0$ and $t_{n+1}:=1$.

Concerning 1. I know that an infill log-likelihood can be obtained by
using Girsanov's theorem, as explained by [Brockwell, Davis and
Yang](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~rdavis/papers/pap2.pdf) or by
[Phillips and
Yu](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.852.120&rep=rep1&type=pdf). However,
this likelihood seems to be conditional on the initial value $y(0)$,
while $y(0)$ is assumed here to be random with its distribution
depending on the model parameters. As a side-effect, the defined
infill-likelihood does not preserve the time-reversibility which
arises from the assumptions here. Intuition suggests that a
contribution accounting for the initial state should be found in the
log-likelihood.

Comment: The term "infill likelihood" is used by some authors in an rather informal acceptation to evocate the likelihood of an infinity of observations such as $\{y(t):\, 0 \leq t \leq 1\}$. Since nothing exists like a Lebesgue measure in an infinite dimensional space, the set of observations does not have a "density". The likelihood is defined by using the Radon-Nikodym derivative w.r.t. a Gaussian measure which does not depend on the parameters e.g. the distribution of a standard Wiener process.

Comment: When applying Girsanov's theorem as P&Y do on p. 5-6, it is assumed
that the distribution of the process $y(t)$ is absolutely continuous
w.r.t. that of the standard Wiener $B(t)$. But this implies that the
probability of $\{y(0) \neq 0\}$ is zero because the distribution of
$y(0)$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. that of $B(0)$ which is Dirac. For the
Ornstein-Ulhenbeck example, no use is made of the stationary
distributionw which  is centred normal with s.d. $\sigma_0 / \sqrt{2 \kappa}$
(on top of p. 6 $\kappa$ seems to be rather $-\kappa$ with $\kappa > 0$).